# REST GET/POST how to send and receive complex parameters?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey and converting my existing data services into RESTful data services. Most simple GETs and PUTs I could successfully convert. But following are some I am not able to convert:

1. X Get (T) // for complex queries with complex result
2. X Post (T) // for creating with complex result
3. X PUT (T) // for updating with some success message object

where T and X are a complex objects

I have tried @queryparam, @pathparam with complex objects on GET with @consume & @produce and those didn't work. Also tried POST (though I really needed GET) with url encoded and that didn't work too.

Please Help. I am in need of sample code that does it.

Answer (score 2):

REST isn't designed to handle complex *queries* as the query is actually the URL. When you retrieve a resource you specify the ID of the resource you want. This is simply a number or string and is easily represented in the URL for example;

```
http://host/employee/57
```

would get you employee 57. If your requirements are more complicated then you might want to use a search method, where you pass several parameters. You could use [`@QueryParam`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) here but this isn't really REST in a pure form.

If you are POSTing or PUTting data then you use the same URL as you would if you were doing a GET, only this time you send data in the content body. As you are able to serialize the object in order to return it to a GET request your client should also be able to serialize it to send it to you in a PUT or POST.

Here's an example of a GET and POST;

```
@XmlType
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  //getters and setters
}


@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeService {

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Employee get(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    Employee e = employeeDao.getEmployee(id);
    if (e != null) {
      return e;
    } else {
      throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }
  }

  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Employee post(Employee employee) {
    return employeeDao.insertEmployee(employee); //Assumes your DAO sets the ID
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you give a sample code of POST that receives and returns a complex object?

Comment: This looks good but doesn't meet my criteria. I am trying for <code> public X POST (T) </code> and not <code> public T POST (T) </code>

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment. But basically what I wanted comparing to your example is to do something like: public Employee post(SearchEmployeeCriteria sec). So essentially searching for an employee with complex set of parameters as part of another object. Your example works if return and parameter object are same but it is not in my example.

Comment: @chan What you are asking for doesn't follow the traditional REST style. A POST should insert data, if you want to retrieve data you should be doing a GET.